# Show convergence in distribution to a bivariate normal vector

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, multivariate-normal-distribution, slutsky-theorem

Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be iid exponential random variables with mean $\theta>0$. Let
$$ \hat\alpha_n:= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \quad \text{and} \quad \hat\beta_n:=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\hat\alpha_n)^2}$$
be two estimators of $\theta$ obtained by the method of moments.

Does the vector $\sqrt{n}(\hat\alpha_n-\theta,\hat\beta_n-\theta) $ converges in distribution to a bivariate normal vector $(V,W)$ as $n\to\infty$?

I am thinking about using Slutsky's theorem. I can prove that
$$ \sqrt{n}\left\{\hat\beta_n^2 -  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\theta)^2\right\} \to 0 \text{ in probability}. $$
I hope to prove that
$$ \sqrt{n}(\hat\alpha_n-\theta,\hat\beta_n-\theta) \text{ and } \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(Y_i-\theta, \frac{(Y_i-\theta)^2-\theta^2}{2\theta}\right) \text{ have the same limiting distribution. } \quad (*) $$
Then by the multivariate central limit theorem for iid random vectors,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(Y_i-\theta, \frac{(Y_i-\theta)^2-\theta^2}{2\theta}\right)$$
converges to bivariate normal distribution with zero mean vector and covariance matrix
$$ \left( \begin{matrix} \text{Var}(Y_i-\theta) & \text{Cov}(Y_i-\theta, (Y_i-\theta)^2/(2\theta)) \\ \text{Cov}(Y_i-\theta, (Y_i-\theta)^2/(2\theta)) & \text{Var}((Y_i-\theta)^2/(2\theta)) \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} \theta^2 & \theta^2  \\ \theta^2  & 2\theta^2  \end{matrix} \right). $$
I'm stuck trying to prove $(*)$. Any suggestions on how to tackle it? Or maybe $(*)$ does not hold at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotic marginal Normality of $\hat \alpha_n$ is trivial.

Use the [**Delta method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) for your $\hat \beta_n$ since it is a non-linear function of the data, to prove its asymptotic marginal Normality.

Use [**Cramer-Wold**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem) theorem to go from the two marginals to the bivariate Normal.

Compute the asymptotic covariance, most likely using again some linearization plus an $o(1)$ term.